# Database schema for files/folders shared to users/groups?

Tags: database, web, schema, document, sharing

i would like to create a simple system for users to share documents with other users OR groups

Currently i have three models

**User** (general user info)

**Document** (has a parent folder)

**Folder** (just a name)

The principles are

- Folders are just one level and contain documents. No hierarchy allowed
- A user can share a folder OR a file to a User OR a group.
- For a User to access a document,  the document OR its parent folder has to be shared with him, or with a group he belongs to.

These last conditions make it very hard to think of the table structure. I would really appreciate any help with this